# Why can't I break blocks on any of my worlds in single player?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I just got Minecraft a few days ago and from the start I could not break a single block except if I used fire or TNT; I even tried all the different tools it just will not work. Please help me?

Comment: Please add some details as there are several questions about unbreakable blocks on `minecraft`. What version are you running, what platform/operating system? Are you using any mods or mod loaders? Is this occurring every time you make a new world?

Comment: Are you holding down the 'punch' button? (Left-Click)

Comment: Well i have the pc version, i have no mods, it does not even react when i press and or hold on the block, and it happens every time i make a new world.

Comment: and what is the punch button